# Google docs OCR on Gmail attachment

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, ocr

I am trying to store the text content of Gmail attachments to Google Drive. I followed steps mentioned here and got a basic OCR script working:
https://medium.com/@aio.phnompenh/make-ocr-tool-in-google-spreadsheet-to-extract-text-from-image-or-pdf-using-google-app-script-c478d4062b8c

This performs OCR on the image linked in valueURL below:

```
var image = UrlFetchApp.fetch(valueURL).getBlob();
```

However, when I try to reference it to a Gmail attachment using:

```
var image = GmailApp.getInboxThreads()[0].getMessages()[0].getAttachments();
```

I get the error:

> The mediaData parameter only supports Blob types for upload.

Can someone let me know how do I resolve this?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`.getAttachments()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getattachments) function returns a array of GmailAttachment[] objects. To get the first attachment or even the only attachment you need to do this:

```
var image = GmailApp.getInboxThreads()[0].getMessages()[0].getAttachments()[0];
```